# Set a custom width to the dropdown list items in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

How do i set a custom width to the dropdown list items in bootstrap 3.0.

I have a dropdown list, but the width of the items is usually the same size for all, and that size is determined by the longest item width.

Is it possible to customize the width and if the item words ar too long to fit, then wrap them?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it just like you would without bootstrap:

```
ul{
    width: 22px;
}
```

i just checked this version and it works.

if this doesn't work try adding !important, it should work

```
ul{
    width: 22px !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` should be avoided if possible. If OP adds a specific `#id` then there would be no need for the `!important` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can customize everything in css and also in bootstrap framwork, when you used dropdown then take css automatic by bootstrap, you can also override this css. you can all css override with the help of `"!important"` property.

You can follow this mathod:

```
width : 100px; or width:100px !important
```

If width also not working then you can try `min-width` property.

```
min-width : 100px; or min-width:100px !important
```

ThankYou.

Comment: It worked. Is it possible to wrap the words if its too long to fit?

Comment: Yup, it's complete work. And if height is very taller then you can set auto property of height.